# SSJS perform data extract

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, automation

Running this script but getting the error : -

> {"message":"Error executing perform call.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Error executing perform call.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionParameterException: Property: PartnerProperties is an array but value to be set was not an array.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Script -

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var action = "Start";
var props = {CustomerKey: "CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
             PartnerProperties : {OutputFilename: "Testing.csv"}
};
var opts = {};
var data = prox.performItem("DataExtractActivity", props, action, opts); 

    
   Write(data);
    
    
</script>

<script runat="server">
  } catch(e) {
  Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

I am trying to perform the dataextract with the variable filename like FILENAMINGPATTERN - should be variable.

Comment: Judging from the error, I think making it an array should resolve it. E.g. ` PartnerProperties: [{OutputFilename: "Testing.csv"}]`

Comment: thanx that error got resolved but Invalid property name: OutputFilename\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" I dont know which property will work here, I am trying to trigger data extract with the new file naming pattern everytime with ssjs

Comment: Hi, are you sure that you can use a 'variable filename' when you 'perform' the data extract? Maybe you can update your data extract with thw new filename and then simply perform it.

Comment: I am not sure that I can use the variable for the data extract but I am trying to use it. Actually I am working on the custom data extract that deletes the file from the safehouse and the FTP. but it works with the static filename but my actual file name has timestamp attached to it which is making this file non deletable that's why I am using ssjs to give the file name in the for loop with the fixed minute till 60minutes to have this file deleted from the extract itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var action = "start"
var props = {ObjectID: "a9af4db2-d10c-4cd0-8949-232f5b314b43", PartnerProperties: [{"Name": "OutputFileName","Value": "Testing.txt"}]};
var opts = {};
var data = prox.performItem("DataExtractActivity", props, action, opts);
```

ObjectID can be retrieved via SOAP or if you do an inspect element on the data extract activity in Marketing Cloud. The code performs the extract but ignores the properties set, meaning you can't update the output filename. And when performing an update, this error shows up

> {"Status":"Error","RequestID":"2ec6c13b-862d-4782-b532-ab0d87398249","Results":[{"Object":null,"UpdateResults":null,"ParentPropertyName":null,"StatusCode":"Error","StatusMessage":"Cannot perform Update on objects of type DataExtractActivity","OrdinalID":0,"ErrorCode":5,"RequestID":null,"ConversationID":null,"OverallStatusCode":null,"RequestType":"Synchronous","ResultType":null,"ResultDetailXML":null}]}